# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scriptDataSourceInitializer' defined in class path resources?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am new in learning spring boot web. I have started learning spring jpa data where I am using h2 database. I wanted to insert test data in it using

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scriptDataSourceInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration$SharedCredentialsDataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/E:/Programing/Java/boot/SpringBootJpa/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into alien values(101,'Rahul','Java'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ALIEN" not found; SQL statement:
insert into alien values(101,'Rahul','Java') [42102-200]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springboot.SpringBootJpaApplication.main(SpringBootJpaApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/E:/Programing/Java/boot/SpringBootJpa/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into alien values(101,'Rahul','Java'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ALIEN" not found; SQL statement:
insert into alien values(101,'Rahul','Java') [42102-200]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:282) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:89) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyDataScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.initializeDatabase(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:76) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ALIEN" not found; SQL statement:
insert into alien values(101,'Rahul','Java') [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7599) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1747) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:954) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:212) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:261) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform==h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:springboot
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

data.sql file

```
insert into alien values(101,'Rahul','Java');
```

Controller class

```
package org.springboot.controller;

import org.springboot.dao.AlienRepo;
import org.springboot.model.Alien;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    AlienRepo repo;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        
        return "home";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/addalien")
    public String addAlien(Alien alien) {
        repo.save(alien);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Repository interface

```
package org.springboot.dao;

import org.springboot.model.Alien;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface AlienRepo extends CrudRepository<Alien, Integer>{

}
```

Entity Class

```
package org.springboot.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Alien {
    
    @Id 
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String tech;
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getTech() {
        return tech;
    }
    public void setTech(String tech) {
        this.tech = tech;
    }
    
    }
```

I also checked the stacktrace which says that alien table not found. But when i checked the h2 console earlier it was showing me the alien table is present.

[image]

Please can you help me?

Comment: When do you get the error? It would seem as if the application is starting correctly since you're able to query the database. To me it looks as if it is trying to insert your initial data before the table has been created, which explains why it's empty when you run your query.

Comment: Actually the screenshot was taken before I created data.sql file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

in appllicat

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 7):

You have to set to tell Spring Boot that first the Hibernate DDL generation is done and then the execute the SQL files.

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

Please read:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the application.properties file is under `src/main/resources` folder
2. Include `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true` in application.properties file

Answer (score 0):

In `application.properties` file under `src/main/resources` folder add this:

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```